# How can I show alertview with activity indicator?

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to show alertview with message: "Loading data" and spinning activity indicator. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can add a label and activityindicator as subviews of your alert view. you have to do  some thing like this

```
myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:@"\n\n"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@""
                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];  

UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];   
loading.frame=CGRectMake(150, 150, 16, 16);
[myAlertView addSubview:loading];
[myAlertView show];
```

..better to use a UIActionSheet in this situation...

Comment: thank you , i will use UIActionSheet + UIActivityIndicatorView

Comment: Why should you use a UIActionSheet in this situation?  (I know Apple would probably agree with you, but I'd like to know why).  You're not using any private APIs, right?

Comment: You're missing  `[loading startAnimating]` and also there are empty buttons showing.

Comment: you would have missed [loading startAnimating]; i guess

Answer (score 27):

**NOTE: This solution won't work on iOS 7 and above.**

This is my take on it:

```
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submitting Entry"
                                       message:@"\n"
                                      delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];   
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
[alertView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView show];
```

and dismiss in code using:

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: use `    spinner.center = CGPointMake(0.0, -spinner.frame.size.height); 
    spinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;` to always position the spinner at the bottom center of your alert

Comment: spinner doesn't show. My alterView only shows Submitting Entry. I am using iOS 7.

Comment: @coolcool1994 This has not been tested on iOS 7. Answer from 2 years ago ;)

Comment: That's true :) I hope I could know the iOS7 way of this :}

Answer (score 25):

**This works on iOS 7**

addSubView doesn't work on UIAlertView in iOS 7 and above. Try this instead

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading data" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];

[alertView setValue:indicator forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alertView show];
```

and to dismiss it

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is the solution that works on iOS 7 (For this comment's current date).

Answer (score 6):

you can add a label and activityindicator as subviews of your alert view. you have to do some thing like this...

```
- (IBAction)showAlertWithActivity:(id)sender{

alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Guardando datos..."
                                            message:@"\n"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
        [alerta addSubview:spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];
        [alerta show];


        [self performSelector:@selector(close) withObject:self afterDelay:1];


    }
    -(void)close{

        [alerta dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add This in your .h file 
`UIAlertView *connectingAlert;`

And Add these two functions in your .m files

```
//show loading activity.
- (void)startSpinner:(NSString *)message {
    //  Purchasing Spinner.
    if (!connectingAlert) {
        connectingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(message,@"")
                                                 message:nil
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
        connectingAlert.tag = (NSUInteger)300;
        [connectingAlert show];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *connectingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        connectingIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(139.0f-18.0f,50.0f,37.0f,37.0f);
        [connectingAlert addSubview:connectingIndicator];
        [connectingIndicator startAnimating];

    }
}
//hide loading activity.
- (void)stopSpinner {
    if (connectingAlert) {
        [connectingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        connectingAlert = nil;
    }
    // [self performSelector:@selector(showBadNews:) withObject:error afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

then call

```
[self startSpinner:@"Your message........"];
[self stopSpinner];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3

```
let loadingAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

loadingAlertController.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: loadingAlertController.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: loadingAlertController.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.4, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ xConstraint, yConstraint])

activityIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
activityIndicator.startAnimating()

let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: loadingAlertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)

loadingAlertController.view.addConstraint(height);

self.present(loadingAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];   
loading.frame=CGRectMake(125, 50, 36, 36);
[loading startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:loading];
[alert show];
```