# "Please Wait" while NSStream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

How would I implement a "Please Wait" alert box while an NSStream gets opened and gets information from a server?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So use `UIAlertView` and maybe throw in a `UIActivityIndicator`. Or you can just present a custom view modally with alpha around `0.5` or something and do a custom job of it.

Comment: How would I place a UIActivityIndicator into an alert view?

Comment: @James: Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906726/how-can-i-do-uialertview-with-activity-indicator) for a nice implementation of just that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer. It shows how to dim the screen with a custom "please wait" view. It also includes the code and Image. Take a look at the screen shot at the bottom of the answer to see how it looks. You will not need to include the email stuff, only the wait screen. Or you can just use a alertview like @Pengone has suggested.

[Locking the Fields in MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields/6287412#6287412)