# how to know app was priviously install on ios device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

There is any way for identify that user is installing my app again? Actually in my app i have a feature user can translate some word for free but after that he have to pay. I am using in app purchase for same. But what if user delete app and install again ? he will be able to translate again for free.How to know app was previously install on that device?

Comment: You should use IAP API to check whether he purchased before. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992681/in-app-purchase-storing-fetching-user-purchase-history-ios

Comment: I know how to check in app purchase is made or not. But what about my free word. means if i install the app and use free character after if app prompt for in app purchase, i remove the app and again install it. I want to restrict such user. If any how i can know that app was install previously and in app purchase don't made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some implementations of in app purchases use the keychain to record purchase flags or freebie flags as you mention.

[This](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html) blog entry will show you how to store and retrieve something from the keychain.

This approach really doesn't to my mind sit well with the principal of sandboxing an application so I expect it's frowned upon by Apple and by purists but if you search SO then you will find other posts relating to in app purchases and using the keychain.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4978852/741626) answer as it seems to be pretty definitive on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Damo, ill Try this later and let you know. I am accepting your ans.

Answer (score 3):

Application goes to the App Store for in app purchases. If user has already bought that item, it returns true to your request. User won't pay it again each time.

[image: diagram]

Comment: I know how to check in app purchase is made or not. But what about my free word. means if i install the app and use free character after if app prompt for in app purchase, i remove the app and again install it. I want to restrict such user. If any how i can know that app was install previously and in app purchase don't made.