# Xcode loading View feature

Tags: objective-c, xcode, loading

I was reading a tutorial a while back and I saw a feature I would love to implement. It was a loading view that took the form of a UIAlertView, and you could customize the image in it and the text. If anybody knows what class that is it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perhaps are looking for [UIAlertView Custom Graphics](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/) or [Create a Custom Alert](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/).

Comment: That wasn't it. It was a specific class, but it's no big deal. Your comment helped and so did his one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906726/how-can-i-do-uialertview-with-activity-indicator