# Adding activity indicator to alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiprogressview

I want to add an activity indicator to alert view, so that the user waits while file download operation is in progress.

I checked one of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906726/how-can-i-show-alertview-with-activity-indicator), it says `addSubView` doesn't work on UIAlertView in iOS 7 and above, so someone suggested using:

```
[alertView setValue:indicator forKey:@"accessoryView"]
```

So, is it the correct way, does it go with HIG of iOS. If not, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: The correct way would be to implement your own alert view.

Comment: Could you please provide appropriate links if any.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to implement your own `UIView` that looks like an alert view and add an a `UIActivityIndicator` to your custom view.  Something like this may be helpful: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 0):

Using UIAlertView for displaying progress of file download itself is not a proper design decision. Ideally you should use alert view only to display alerts or prompts? People use it for user input as well but not really recommended.

I would either use plain UIActivityIndicatorView or UIProgressView to display your actual download progress.

Answer (score 0):

It's not typical to add subviews to `UIAlertView` I would rather use one of the library to present alert and activity indicator.

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) or [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD)

Comment: Do I need mention them somewhere or so. And will they pass HIG?

Comment: It's totally up to you if you want to attribute them, also most common apps use them and you don't need to worry about HIG