# Indicator within alert, indicator doesn't show up (resolved using UIAlertController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to follow the accepted solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906726/how-can-i-show-alertview-with-activity-indicator) on Xcode 6.3.2 but the indicator refuses to show up or I can't see it on my iPhone 6 plus for some reason. No error messages, the alert with the title, etc shows up and empty space.

What am I doing wrong? The alert is triggered after the connect button on the app is pressed...

```
UIAlertView *alertWithInd;
UIActivityIndicatorView *alertInd;
alertWithInd = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connecting..." message:@"Please wait...\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

alertInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
alertInd.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 270, 100);
[alertInd startAnimating];

[alertWithInd addSubview:alertInd];
[alertWithInd show];
```

Comment: `addSubview ` for `UIAlertView` is no longer supportable.

Comment: try UIAlertViewController

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ, and how should that help? He won't be able to add the indicator there as-well.

Comment: In Swift with a UIAlertViewController I'm able to show a UIPIcker so can I show an indicator as well?

Comment: you can add subview ..

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ, and how would you do that? how would that differ to the current solution and how would it be compliant with the subclassing notes?

Comment: Found this [blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html) that proposes what @MOHAMMADISHAQ was saying, is this not good as I believe UIAlertController was introduced for this purpose, so it can be modified...?

Comment: You got desired result , If you want a more better way you can make a shared custom alert view via using UIView , add/Remove at UIWindow .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some further research and for anyone else interested in finding the solution in one spot (as there are parts in many other posts) I post the code that uses an UIAlertController (instead of a UIAlert), has an indicator and also the code for dismissal without the need for a button to be pressed.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Connecting"
                                      message:@"Please wait...\n\n"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


UIActivityIndicatorView *alertInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
alertInd.frame=CGRectMake(0, 40, 270, 100);
[alertInd startAnimating];

[alertController.view addSubview:alertInd];


id rootViewController=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
    rootViewController=[((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
[rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

// to dismiss the alert with no button use:
[alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thanks a bunch :) The only question I have is whether the alertInd frame can be sized programmatically, and not hard-coded. Although it's not the end of the world if we can't :)

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

> ### Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. **The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.**

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same issue in my one of project . I have resolved this in this way -

Define below in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *alertViewProcessing;
```

.m file -

```
-(void)processing
{


    self.alertViewProcessing = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Requesting...." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [indicator startAnimating];


    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
        view.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        indicator.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0 );
        [view addSubview:indicator];

        [self.alertViewProcessing setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.alertViewProcessing setValue:indicator forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    }

    [self.alertViewProcessing show];

}
```

Comment: while this might work technically it violates the rule "**The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**"